# function from header breaks after receive input

Tags: arrays, c, string

I am writing a simple shell for a project and I need to print out the time on the prompt using syscalls. I wrote this function in a header file:

```
char * timef() {
    int tempo;
    tempo = syscall(201) % 86400;
    int hora = (tempo / 3600) - 3;
    int minutos = (tempo / 60) % 60;
    int segundos = tempo % 60;
    char *str = malloc(9);
    str[0] = hora/10 + '0';
    str[1] = hora%10 + '0';
    str[2] = ':';
    str[3] = minutos/10 + '0';
    str[4] = minutos%10 + '0';
    str[5] = ':';
    str[6] = segundos/10 + '0';
    str[7] = segundos%10 + '0';
    str[8] = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

Then, in the Main() function, I have this:

```
while (flag == 1){
        printf("%s: ", timef());
        char letra;
        scanf("%c", &letra);
        if (letra == 'q') flag = 0;
    }
```

When I run, the first line gets time correctly, but after I get any input, it totally breaks:

```
20:09:36: a
0-:00:0/: 0-:00:0/: a
0-:00:0/: 0-:00:0/:
```

What should I do? I have tested to just print the time in loop and it updates the seconds.

Expected:

```
20:09:36: a
20:09:39: a
20:09:42: a
20:09:48: a
20:09:50:
```

Actual results:

```
20:09:36: a
0-:00:0/: 0-:00:0/: a
0-:00:0/: 0-:00:0/:
```

(yes, it printed twice in the same line)

Comment: Asides: You are leaking memory, the function definition of timef() doesn't belong in a header file.

Comment: int hora = (tempo / 3600) **- 3**; ??

Comment: Don't hardwire syscall numbers. These can change from system to system. Use `__NR_*` instead. But, for time values, don't use `syscall`. The libc functions (e.g. `clock_gettime` et. al.) are mapped into the app itself (via the VDSO) so that you can get the time values _without_ the overhead of a syscall. With the VDSO, the requisite clock values are mapped into userspace. The libc functions know how to get at these values directly (i.e. they are _faster_ than a naked syscall).

Comment: [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Comment: @AviBerger: hardcoded timezone, indicating the OP is probably in Brazil.

Comment: @ChrisDodd, makes sense, but in that case it doesn't handle times before 3 AM.

Comment: @AviBerger, yes, the time will be corrupted between 9pm and midnight, but the OP is testing at 8:09pm so hasn't noticed it yet.

Answer (score 2):

The duplicate output is due to `scanf` leaving the newline in the input (so you get two outputs per input line, one for the character you type and one for the enter/newline)

The weird time (`0-:00:0/`) is due to sycall returning -1 (an error).
In this case, the syscall (time) is expecting an additional argument (an address to write the time to in addition to returning it).  When you call with fewer args like this, it will get whatever value happens to be in the register that would be used for it, and if that is not 0 and doesn't point at valid memory, you get an error.

To fix these, you can add a space in the scanf argument (`scanf(" %c", &letra);` to ignore the newline and add a 0 or NULL to the syscall (`syscall(201, 0)`).  Better yet, call `time(0)` instead.

You could also use `int hora = ((tempo / 3600) + 21) % 24;` to make your timezone adjustment work properly after 9pm.